# Recursive Java, Checking for conflicts between nodes

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to configure out a method for checking conflicts between the head and all of the other nodes. At this point, I'm getting stuck in a loop. Any idea how to loop through the list, comparing head with head.next .next .next.next and so on?

**EDIT: After adding a return false; after the conflictCheck(a,b.getNext()), there is no longer the loop problem but the output reflects this method NOT comparing each node with the head node.**

**EDIT X 2! : I believe I have the loop checking for conflicts working fine thanks to everyone who commented/answered. Now I have strange results in my program,where conflicts are being detected but nothing is being done about them. I've added my other important method that deals with these shenanigans. Also, my output is below. Is there any reason why Every node's column is moving to either 3, or staying at 1???**

```
    public static void playChess() {
    System.out.println("Playing chess");
    if (conflictCheck(head, head.getNext())) {
        if (head.getColumn() == 8) {
            queens.pop();
        }
        else if (!queens.isEmpty() && head.getColumn()!= 8) {
            System.out.println("Adjusting head");
            head.setColumn(head.getColumn()+1);
            System.out.println("Head is now " + head.getRow() + ", " + head.getColumn());
            playChess();

        }
    }

    else if (queens.size() < 8) {
        System.out.println("Stack isn't full yet");
        queens.push(queens.size()+1,1);
        queens.viewPieces();
        playChess();
        }
    else {
        success= true;
        System.out.println("Success");
        queens.viewPieces();
        return;
    }
}


    public static boolean conflictCheck(QueenNode a, QueenNode b) {
    //checks for conflicts between head and all other nodes in the stack
    a= head;
    while (b != null) {
        if (a.getRow()!=b.getRow() && a.getColumn()!=b.getColumn() && !diagonal(a,b)){
            conflictCheck(a,b.getNext());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("There is a conflict");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My output

Playing chess
Comparing 8 ,3 And 7 , 1 
**There is a conflict with 8,3 And 6,3** 
Success
 The stack
 8, 3
 7, 1 
6, 3 
5, 1 
4, 3 
3, 1 
2, 3
1, 1 
End of stack

Comment: Is this homework?  We'll be better able to help you if you let us know.

Comment: Yes, it is! I really feel like this is close but am mixing up a line somewhere or something

Comment: And why `while (b != null) {` - you don't appear to ever be changing `b`.

Comment: I thought that the results of 1,1-2,3-3,1-4,3...etc were becuase the loop wasn't comparing the head with each node. If it did that from the start, you'd never have a problem, because the head should be immediately adjusted. But my program is PRINTING that there's a conflict sometimes and then leaving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing the cycle with the recursive call.

If I understand you correctly, you would want something like:

```
public static boolean conflictCheck(QueenNode a, QueenNode b) {
//checks for conflicts between head and all other nodes in the stack

    if (b == null){
        return false;
    }
    if (a.getRow()!=b.getRow() && a.getColumn()!=b.getColumn() && !diagonal(a,b)){
        return conflictCheck(a,b.getNext());
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("There is a conflict");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I didn't run the code, so I'm hoping you get the picture, there's probably a syntax error or 4.

Comment: I think that is what I want, I just didn't know how/where to check if b was null. One thing though, the method marks an error if I don't add a return line outside of those loops. Do I just default it to false?

Comment: Yes, I would just default it to false. I don't think it'll ever happen, but Java doesn't know that (actually, if your "linked list" has a loop, you could go in a cycle, but that's a different matter).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As noted above, you also need a condition to end the recursion which I didnt include here - test if b is null sounds right.

The recursive call doesn't look right.
You would need to setup your initial a and b variable inside the block calling this recursive method, not inside the recursive method.

```
//...
a = nodes.head;
b = nodes.getNext();

if(conflictCheck(a, b)) {
    //... there is a conflict
}
```

and then your method should look something like :

```
public static boolean conflictCheck(QueenNode a, QueenNode b) {

    if (a.getRow()!=b.getRow() && a.getColumn()!=b.getColumn() && !diagonal(a,b)){
        // there is no conflict here, check one step further into the list and return the result
        return conflictCheck(a,b.getNext());
    }
    else {
        // there is a conflict, stop here
        System.out.println("There is a conflict");
        return true;
    }
}
```

HTH